# Save shared documents to my sharepoint as a weblink

Tags: links

[image]

Somehow, I saved documents from a shared group SharePoint folder to my personal SharePoint as webpages (see 4th and last icon in the picture). When I click the webpage from my personal SharePoint, it opens the document in the group folder. I think this is fantastic for organizing all the documents I'm working on in one place vice navigating through many different shared folders. Problem is I don't recall how I saved the doc as a webpage. It would be great if someone can share the instructions on how. (Apologies if the "webpage" terminology isn't correct here.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have used SharePoint's "Add shortcut to OneDrive" feature. You'll find the button in the action bar in SharePoint document libraries. It creates a shortcut to get to the library documents quickly when you are in your OneDrive. More information can be found here:

[Add shortcuts to shared folders in OneDrive for work or school](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-shortcuts-to-shared-folders-in-onedrive-for-work-or-school-d66b1347-99b7-4470-9360-ffc048d35a33#:%7E:text=In%20OneDrive%2C%20in%20the%20navigation,Add%20shortcut%20to%20My%20files.)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason my OneDrive doesn't have a Shared folder. I only have Desktop, Documents, Pictures, and Microsoft Teams. I added all the folders I was allowed to, but Shared wasn't listed as an option. I'll try to look into this further.